# Closure Capture Memory Leak issue with UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, closures

In `willDisplay` method, I get `UIImage` and `IndexPath` from a callback closure. I am using `tableView` inside that closure. Should I need to make that tableView `weak` to avoid possible memory leaks, or is it not an issue to use `strong` `tableView`?

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    guard let cell = cell as? ArtistTableViewCell else { return }
    guard let imageUrl = cell.viewModel.artistImage() else { return }

    // Download image callback closure returns UIImage, IndexPath, and error
    ImageDownloadService.shared.downloadImage(imageUrl,indexPath:indexPath) { [weak tableView] (image, index, error) in
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            guard let getIndexPath = index else { return }
            guard let getImage = image else { return }
            guard let getCell = tableView?.cellForRow(at: getIndexPath) as? ArtistTableViewCell else { return }

            getCell.setArtistImage(getImage)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It’s not necessary to capture `tableView` explicitly because it’s provided as local variable in the first parameter of the `willDisplay` method.

Therefore it will not cause a memory leak.

There is a simple rule: Don’t capture anything which is locally accessible inside the method.

Feel free to prove it with Instruments.

Comment: what i get from your answer is  no need to use Tableview weakly in this case ?

Comment: Yes, “not necessary” == *no need*

Comment: While this is true in almost all cases; in this case, if you don't use tableview weakly, you will cause a memory leak.

Comment: @Giorgio You won't because – as already mentioned – the **parameter** `tableView` is a local variable which is weak anyway.

Comment: @vadian The parameter `tableView` is a local variable, but it is a reference to `tableView` object strong retained by `UITableViewController` and this will cause a retain cycle. Try with a sample project if you doubt me.

Answer (score 1):

Locale variables are not captured by closure as they are within the same scope, so you don't need to make tableview as weak reference.

Answer (score 0):

`weak` is preferred. If you retain the `tableView` and dismiss the view controller while it downloads an image the table view object (and its cells) won't be deallocated until the call download finishes. (however no retain cycle will occur)

Comment: if let getIndexPath = index,let getImage = image, let getCell = tableView.cellForRow(at: getIndexPath) as? ArtistTableViewCell 

this check will fail if cell is not visible so next code will not execute which set image

Comment: i use NSCache to cache that image for the next time ... that logic is in ImageDownloader  class

Comment: tableView here is not global variable ... yet i need to declare it weak ?

Comment: yes otherwise it will be retained by the block. Not a big issue though but if you want to make sure everything is deallocated once you dismiss the VC then weak is the way to go